# Coordinates of $P$ that divide a vector line in a ratio.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

For $A(3, -1, 1)$ and $B(0, 2, -1)$, find the:

a) Vector equation of the line passing through A and B.
b) The coordinates of P which divides BA in the ratio 2:5.

For a), I got the answer $\langle x, y, z\rangle = \langle 3 - 3t, -1 + 3t, 1 - 2t\rangle$.

However, for b), I figure that the magnitude of BP will be $2.5$ times that of PA's magnitude. Thus, I find vector BP and PA. for BP, I get $\langle 3 - 3t, 3t - 3, 2t - 2\rangle$. For PA, I get $\langle 3t, -3t, 2t\rangle$.

I do the following:

$5(22t^2 - 44t + 22) = 2\sqrt{22}t$

However, by solving with Wolframalpha, I always get a very obscure decimal answer that just doesn't work out.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You’ve parametrized the line so that at $t=0$ you get point $A$ and at $t=1$ you get point $B$. What value of $t$ might get you $\frac27$ of the way from $B$?